# Prisma many-to-many with createMany

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have this prisma schema(every post could have many phones, and every phone could have many posts)

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  text String
  phones  Phone[]
}

model Phone {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  phone  String     @unique
  posts Post[]
}
```

And this code works fine, but since it inserts the data one at a time, it's slow. Is it possible to convert it to createMany?

```
const posts = [
  {
    text: "First post",
    phones: [
      { phone: "1234567890" },
      { phone: "9876543210" }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: "Second post",
    phones: [
      { phone: "5555555555" },
      { phone: "9999999999" }
    ]
  }
];

createPostsAndPhones(posts);

    async function createPostsAndPhones(posts) {
        const prisma = new PrismaClient();
        try {
            for (const post of posts) {
                const createdPost = await prisma.post.create({
                    data: {
                        text: post.text,
                        phones: {
                            connectOrCreate: post.phones.map(phone => ({
                                where: { phone: phone.phone },
                                create: { phone: phone.phone }
                            }))
                        }
                    },
                    include: {
                        phones: true
                    }
                });
                console.log("Created Post:", createdPost);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error creating Posts:", error);
        } finally {
            await prisma.$disconnect();
        }
    }
```

I tried this, but got the error

```
  const createdPosts = await prisma.post.createMany({
                data: posts.map(({ text, phones }) => ({
                    text,
                    phones: {
                        connectOrCreate: phones.map(phone => ({
                            where: { phone },
                            create: { phone }
                        }))
                    }
                }))
            });
```

> Unknown arg `phones` in data.0.phones for type PostCreateManyInput.
> Available args:
> type PostCreateManyInput {
> id?: Int
> text: String
> }

Answer (score 0):

createMany works only on a single entity and not on sub-entities.

reference: [Nested relations using createMany](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/5455)